# Add a day to an ending date in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two datepicker modules in Angular, one is a start date and one is an end date.  The start date looks like this:

`{{startDate| date: 'EEE, MMM d'}}`

I want to do something with the end date where it would be at least a day after the start date where it would be something like

`{{endDate| date: 'EEE, MMM d+1'}}`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
{{startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1)| date: 'EEE, MMM d'}}
```

or, if you want to have an endDate variable that gets updated in javascript based on some event you could add this to your controller:

```
$scope.setEndDate = function(){
    $scope.endDate = $scope.startDate.setDate($scope.startDate.getDate() + 1); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using a library like [momentJS](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: This is a comment .. Not an answer.

Comment: thank you jamrizzi.. i am wondering if there is a way to do this purely angular?